# Cleanly replace current Haskell process (exec)

Tags: haskell, exec

I'm writing a Haskell program whose sole purpose is to execute another (non-Haskell) program, after gathering some info to determine what arguments that program should be executed with.

Replacing a running Haskell process is easy enough using `executeFile`, but I'm wondering if there's a way to ensure the Haskell program properly cleans up after itself before it's replaced.

For example, `Control.Exception.finally` is normally useful to ensure cleanup actions are performed even if an exception occurs, but it will have no effect if we exec a whole different process:

```
module Main (main) where

import Control.Exception    (finally)
import System.Posix.Process (executeFile)

main = finally (do putStrLn "opening file descriptors"
                   putStrLn "writing temporary files"
                   executeFile "ls" True [] Nothing)
               (putStrLn "cleaning up")
```

The above example will never print "cleaning up".

Is there a recommended way to perform such a maneuver "cleanly"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the `executeFile` *after* `finally`, because it completely replaces *any* code from the Haskell program.

```
main = do
    finally (putStrLn "opening" >> putStrLn "writing") (putStrLn "cleaning up")
    executeFile "ls" True [] Nothing
```

The only exception that can occur from `executeFile` is a problem with the exec itself, but you have to proceed as if the exec will work and you aren't coming back to the Haskell code; it's a one-way `goto`, not a subroutine call.

Comment: Your last paragraph seems incorrect; if the `exec` syscall fails, then `executeFile` throws an exception that can be caught like any other. It's only if the `exec` syscall succeeds, but then something goes wrong with the new program, that there's no going back.

Comment: Yes, but presumably there's nothing else to clean up at that point. You can catch the exception, maybe log why `ls` didn't run, but anything else that should have been done before running `ls` needs to already have been done.

Answer (score 3):

There's really nothing Haskell-specific about this. If you want to do things after a process is done, you can't just [`exec(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html)/[`executeFile`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.2.2/docs/System-Posix-Process.html#v:executeFile) it. You must instead [`fork(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)/[`forkProcess`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.2.2/docs/System-Posix-Process.html#v:forkProcess), then in the parent, do [`waitpid(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html)/[`getProcessStatus`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.2.2/docs/System-Posix-Process.html#v:getProcessStatus) on the child, and do your cleanup once that returns.

---

Edit: The above is to clean up after the new process is done. If you don't care about that, and just want to clean up when your Haskell is done but the new process is still running, then chepner's answer will work.